# ASP .Net Core 5 web application crashes in Fully-kiosk app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kiosk, kiosk-mode

For the first time, I'm using [fully-kiosk](https://www.fully-kiosk.com/en/#download-box) on a [PROVX](https://www.prodvx.com/) Android, version 9

I set up the website that I want to open when the user starts up the device but the page crashes.

The website is an ASP .Net Core 5 web application, published in Azure and it works perfectly on any other device and browsers (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge...). I don't get any error messages from the browser.

I wanted to know which browser uses the [PROVX](https://www.prodvx.com/) to load the setup website, so maybe I will adapt the application to load up correctly.

Comment: What does `the page crashes` mean? Empty page? ASP.NET Core error page? Did you check the server logs? If the web site throws, the logs will have the exception. If you haven't configured logging, do so

Comment: The page is loaded corectly, I see all content of the page with the right style but the buttons in the page do nothing on click. I tried the same page in  [this kiosk mode](https://www.hexnode.com/) and it works perfectly

Comment: Again this means nothing at all. Did you check your site's logs? Are there any requests made there? If not, the problem is on the client entirely. If you use Javascript, did you add error checking? Does the browser have a console you can check? How were you going to monitor the kiosks in the first place? Can you use the same mechanism to log errors?

Comment: `I don't get any error messages from the browser.` this means nothing too. JavaScript errors don't display anything, they're written to the browser console. You'd have to catch exceptions and notify the user explicitly, eg with an alert or modal window.